# Trying to populate labels based on URL parameters in WordPress Gravity forms plugin

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

We are working on a multilingual website which has Arabic version of an application form. We are using Gravity forms for the registration/application process.

On this [link](https://futurepioneersaward.com/ar/apply/?lang=ar). We are trying to update the labels of the fields using gf_pre_render filter. It works fine for the main field label but when we try to access the choices array and update them it does not work.

We are trying to update the labels of the fields using gf_pre_render filter. It works fine for the main field label but when we try to access the choices array and update them it does not work.

Comment: Just wonder why cant you use gform_field_choices

Comment: We tried but for some reason it does not work! :(